# IPython autoreload gives error for repeated calls to Python2 super()

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, super

I am prototyping stuff in an IPython notebook that is loading Python2 code from modules on my computer. I activated reloading magic commands to make it easier to go back-and-forth between my text editor and the notebook when I make a code change and re-run a cell to see its affect:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

I am working in Python 2.7.10 because I working with some legacy code that doesn't compile for 3. Part of my work is extending some classes in this legacy code and overloading some of their methods. But, I also need to call some of the original base methods to do important work. For example:

```
class LegacyBase:

    def important_method(self):
        #old stuff i'll need

class NewClass(LegacyBase):

    #overload base method
    def important_method(self):
       #do some new stuff

       while 1:
           #call old method to do stuff
           super(NewClass, self).important_method() #use old Python2 super calls :(

           #some break conditions
```

When I call `important_method()` with some `NewClass` instance the first time in my notebook (meaning, after a kernel reset) it runs fine. The loop is such that the `super` call is happening more than once! No errors

But, if I go and modify some code to my new method in my text editor and go back to the IPython cell and call it again I get the following error at the line in my overloaded `important_method()` where the `super` call is made.

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

***Note:*** I tried just naming my new method a different name because I thought it was something to do with the overloading method calling itself again but that didn't help. Also, I want them to be the same name because this is an API method and I want users of the legacy code to be able to call the same methods they know from before.

Any idea how to use reloading in IPython notebooks with these Python2 `super` calls?

Thanks!

Comment: This is f****g annoying... can't use super at all currently if I intend to Jupyter notebooks...

Comment: What often works for me is explicitly deleting the old class, importing it again, then creating a new instance of the class. So in your case `del NewClass; import NewClass; nc = NewClass(); nc.important_method()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing instances are still pointing to the old class from before the reload.

You need to either re-create the instances, or update their `__class__` attribute:

```
instance_of_newclass.__class__ = NewClass
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response (not the first time; really, thanks!). But I don't get why calling the method (which calls several super calls) would suddenly make my instance (which was defined as an instance of the new class) point to it's super?

Comment: The exception tells you that the *second* argument (`self`) is not an instance of the first argument (`NewClass`). That's because `issubclass(self.__class__, NewClass)` is no longer true; you have a *new* class (loaded from your updated file).

Comment: do you know of any iPython command that will clear all of its "memory" so this doesn't happen in the terminal shell? I do `run my_script.py` then make some changes to the code and when I call `run my_scirpt.py` I get this error. I don't want to reset some instance's class like you said here for the notebook. I just want a (magic?) command that will "clear" everything ipython remembers so i can just call `run my_scirpt.py again` without having to exit the ipython shell and come back.

Comment: Btw, I have setup so that `%load_ext autoreload` and `autoreload 2` are added to any ipython shell session through the profile configuration, so those are active in my shell

Comment: @river_jones: I don't, sorry. I don't use IPython myself.

Comment: this is friggin super annoying! Updating the class attributes is also not working, dammit... anyone have a solution?

Comment: This behaviour is not likely to change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Recreating the instance doesn't work here. I need to put `self.__class__ = NewClass` before invoking `super` to get it work. You mention that `instance_of_newclass.__class__ = NewClass` but how this work? I mean, is this should be put before or after a instance is created? Both doesn't work here... It seems that I need to put it into `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

### Reproducing the problem

I use a module `reload_test.py` modeled after your example:

```
class LegacyBase:

    def important_method(self):
        print 'doing'

class NewClass(LegacyBase):

    def important_method(self):
        for x in range(3):
            super(NewClass, self).important_method()
```

In my IPython Notebook:

```
In [1]: %reload_ext autoreload
        %autoreload 2

In [2]: import reload_test

In [3]: nc = reload_test.NewClass()
```

Calling a method throws this exception:

```
In [4]: nc.important_method()

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-09eb0eac244b> in <module>()
    ----> 1 nc.important_method()

    /Users/mike/tmp/reload_test.py in important_method(self)
          9 
         10        for x in range(3):
    ---> 11            super(NewClass, self).important_method()

    TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

The class `LegacyBase` needs to inherit from `object`:

```
class LegacyBase(object):

    def important_method(self):
        print 'doing'

class NewClass(LegacyBase):

    def important_method(self):
        for x in range(3):
            super(NewClass, self).important_method()
```

Now, I can reproduce your problem. Works the first time:

```
In [5]: nc = reload_test.NewClass()

In [6]: nc.important_method()
    doing
    doing
    doing
```

After modifying the file in an editor:

```
class LegacyBase(object):

    def important_method(self):
        print 'doing'

class NewClass(LegacyBase):

    def important_method(self):
        for x in range(3):
            super(NewClass, self).important_method()
```

Calling the methods throws an exception:

```
In [7]: nc.important_method()

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-8-09eb0eac244b> in <module>()
    ----> 1 nc.important_method()

    /Users/mike/tmp/reload_test.py in important_method(self)
          9 
         10        for x in range(3):
    ---> 11            super(NewClass, self).important_method()

    TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

### Solution

Just make a new instance:

```
In [8]: nc = reload_test.NewClass()

In [9]: nc.important_method()
    doing 2
    doing 2
    doing 2
```

In practice this means just re-executing the cell that holds `nc = reload_test.NewClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit hacky, but I found setting the parent methods to new attributes in the constructor would enable auto-reloading.

```
class LegacyBase:

    def important_method(self):
        #old stuff i'll need

class NewClass(LegacyBase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__parent_important_method = super(NewClass, self).important_method
        super(NewClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #overload base method
    def important_method(self):
       #do some new stuff

       while 1:
           #call old method to do stuff
           self.__parent_important_method()
           #some break conditions
```